# Take n-dimensional array and bind n-1-dimensional array in r

Tags: r, arrays

I have an n-dimensional array and want to bind an n-1-dimensional array to the start/end mapped across a particular set of dimensions.

Here is a simplified version of the problem: I have a 3D array and want to bind a 2D array (aka matrix) to the end of the 3D array. Specifically, I want the rows of the 2D array to map to the deps of the 3D array and I want the cols of the 2D array to map to the cols of the 3D array (aka adding a matrix slice to the bottom of the array). Visually, if we think of a stack of R programming books (3D array), this is like adding Hadley Wickham's newest R book (2D array) to the bottom of the stack.

I assume this is possible with `abind::abind()`, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I tried `abind::abind(array3D, array2D, along = c(3,2))`, but `abind::abind()` gave me an error saying it does not allow `along` to be multiple dimensions. I also tried the "opposite" with `abind::abind(array3D, array2D, along = 1)` and I still got an error saying the dimensions were incorrect.

As an analogy, my goal is conceptually similar to `rbind(matrix, vector)`

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(abind)
array3D <- array(data = c(111, 211, 311,
                          121, 221, 321,
                             112, 212, 312,
                             122, 222, 322,
                                113, 213, 313,
                                123, 223, 323,
                                   114, 214, 314,
                                   124, 224, 324),
                 dim = c(3,2,4),
                 dimnames = list("row" = c("row1","row2","row3"),
                                 "col" = c("col1","col2"),
                                 "dep" = c("dep1","dep2","dep3","dep4")))

array2D <- array(data = c(411, 412, 413, 414,
                          421, 422, 423, 424),
                 dim = c(4,2),
                 dimnames = list("dep" = c("dep1","dep2","dep3","dep4"),
                                 "col" = c("col1","col2")))

abindError <- abind(array3D, array2D, along = c(3,2))

Error in abind(array3D, array2D, along = c(3, 2)) : "along" must specify one dimension of the array, or interpolate between two dimensions of the array

abindError <- abind(array3D, array2D, along = 1)

Error in abind(array3D, array2D, along = 1) : arg 'X2' has dims=1, 4, 2; but need dims=X, 2, 4

desiredResult <- array(data = c(111, 211, 311, 411,
                                121, 221, 321, 421,
                                   112, 212, 312, 412,
                                   122, 222, 322, 422,
                                      113, 213, 313, 413,
                                      123, 223, 323, 423, 
                                         114, 214, 314, 414,
                                         124, 224, 324, 424),
               dim = c(4,2,4),
               dimnames = list("row" = c("row1","row2","row3","row4"),
                               "col" = c("col1","col2"),
                               "dep" = c("dep1","dep2","dep3","dep4")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding arrays with dims over 2 can be mind-warping, and I don't always know how to explain it other than a little bit of trial-and-error until the error about dimensions goes away (and the intended output is achieved).

In this case, your second attempt was close, and the hint was in the error message:

> arg 'X2' has dims=1, 4, 2; but need dims=X, 2, 4

To go from `4, 2` to `2, 4` (with a 2D array) to me sounds like a `t`ransform, so we can use that:

```r
abind::abind(array3D, t(array2D), along = 1)
# , , dep1
#      col1 col2
# row1  111  121
# row2  211  221
# row3  311  321
#       411  421
# , , dep2
#      col1 col2
# row1  112  122
# row2  212  222
# row3  312  322
#       412  422
# , , dep3
#      col1 col2
# row1  113  123
# row2  213  223
# row3  313  323
#       413  423
# , , dep4
#      col1 col2
# row1  114  124
# row2  214  224
# row3  314  324
#       414  424

all(abind::abind(array3D, t(array2D), along = 1) == desiredResult)
# [1] TRUE
### except for the names, of course
```

I don't know how to preserve the names on the resulting array in the binding call (no combination of the arguments did it on cursory inspection). It should be feasible to automate this with some manual work, but I can't think of an easily-automated method at the moment.

Comment: This also works for values but is not as compact as the answer above: `aperm(abind(aperm(array3D, 3:1), array2D), 3:1)`

Comment: Ah I see. I needed to permute one array to match the other array. So it seems whenever binding arrays with `abind::abind()`, you need to first check the permutations of your arrays. And then `along` will be the dimension of the n-dimensional array that the n-1-dimensional array does not have. Makes sense. Thank you both for the quick reply!

Comment: Here is a simple function that can help identify whether/how arrays need to be permuted in order to be binded via `abind::abind()`:  `arrayBindTest <- function(Narray, N1array, dimNarray2bindAlong) {
   list("Narray" = dim(Narray)[-dimNarray2bindAlong],
         "N1array" = dim(N1array),
         "Test" = identical(dim(Narray)[-dimNarray2bindAlong], dim(N1array)))
}`
`arrayBindTest(Narray = array3D, N1array = array2D, dimNarray2bindAlong = 1)`
`arrayBindTest(Narray = array3D, N1array = t(array2D), dimNarray2bindAlong = 1)`